# Call an autocomplete function on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, autocomplete

after a long search i can't find a way to call an autocomplete function when the document is ready passing a specific variable.

So i got this function that works fine when i select element from autocomplete:

```
var option_row = <?php echo $option_row; ?>;

    $('input[name=\'option\']').autocomplete({
        'source': function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php?route=catalog/option/autocomplete&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&filter_name=' +  encodeURIComponent(request),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(json) {
                    response($.map(json, function(item) {
                        return {
                            category: item['category'],
                            label: item['name'],
                            value: item['option_id'],
                            type: item['type'],
                            option_value: item['option_value']
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        'select': function(item) {

            html  = '<div class="tab-pane" id="tab-option' + option_row + '">';
            html += '   <input type="hidden" name="product_option[' + option_row + '][product_option_id]" value="" />';
            html += '   <input type="hidden" name="product_option[' + option_row + '][name]" value="' + item['label'] + '" />';

    etc etc......
```

after many research i'm thinking to switch to another possible solution...

I wish to call this directly without select item but passing a variable to the function...

i'm trying doing this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(e){

    var option_row = <?php echo $option_row; ?>;
    var req = 'item';
    setOptions(req);

    });

    function setOptions(req){

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?route=catalog/option/autocomplete&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&filter_name=' +  encodeURIComponent(req),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(json) {
                        response($.map(json, function(item) {
                            return {
                                category: item['category'],
                                label: item['name'],
                                value: item['option_id'],
                                type: item['type'],
                                option_value: item['option_value']
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });

           'select': function(item) {

                html  = '<div class="tab-pane" id="tab-option' + option_row + '">';
                html += '   <input type="hidden" name="product_option[' + option_row + '][product_option_id]" value="" />';
                html += '   <input type="hidden" name="product_option[' + option_row + '][name]" value="' + item['label'] + '" />';

           etc, etc...


    }
```

Now, i don't know what i should use instead of `'select': function(item) {` to make it works.

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i have finally make it... it was more simple than i thought

this is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var data = 'Adulti';
    addOptions(data);

});

var option_row = <?php echo $option_row; ?>;


function addOptions(data){

var base_url = 'index.php?route=catalog/option/autocomplete&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&filter_name=' +  encodeURIComponent(data);
var n='';
    $.ajax({

        url: base_url, 

        dataType: 'json',   
        success: function(json) {               

                $.map(json, function(item) {     

                     category = item['category'];
                        label = item['name'];
                        value = item['option_id'];
                         type = item['type'];
                 option_value = item['option_value']; 

        html  = '<div class="tab-pane" id="tab-option' + option_row + '">';
        html += '   <input type="hidden" name="product_option[' + option_row + '][product_option_id]" value="" />';
        html += '   <input type="hidden" name="product_option[' + option_row + '][name]" value="' + item['name'] + '" />';
        html += '   <input type="hidden" name="product_option[' + option_row + '][option_id]" value="' + item['value'] + '" />';
        html += '   <input type="hidden" name="product_option[' + option_row + '][type]" value="' + item['type'] + '" />';

etc, etc....
```